# How do I select a bunch of excel files in sets and execute code for each set of files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder with close to 400 excel files. All of them are grouped in a kind of set and each of them follows this format:

- [Seller_Number]-[Seller_Name].xlsx
- [Seller_Number]-[Seller_Name]-Debit.xlsx
- [Seller_Number]-[Seller_Name]-Resume.xlsx

I want to run a vba macro that executes a block of code for each set.

I basically have this working but I have to select one set at a time, which makes it very time consuming.

**MY CODE FOR ONE SET**

```
Sub macro()

    Dim i As Integer
        
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Filters.clear
        
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*"
        
        If .Show = True Then
            For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
                'Open file
                Dim wb As Workbook
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(i))
                                
                If InStr(.SelectedItems(i), "-RESUME") Then
                    Range("A1").Select
                    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
                    Selection.copy
                    Windows("Comission_TEMPLATE.xlsm").Activate
                    Sheets(2).Select
                    Range("A1").Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste   
                Else
                    If InStr(.SelectedItems(i), "-DEBIT") Then
                        Range("A1").Select
                        Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
                        Selection.copy
                        Windows("Comission_TEMPLATE.xlsm").Activate
                        Sheets(2).Select
                        Range("A5").Select
                        ActiveSheet.Paste   
                    Else
                        Range("A2").Select
                        Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
                        Selection.copy
                        Windows("Comission_TEMPLATE.xlsm").Activate
                        Sheets(1).Select
                        Range("A25").Select
                        ActiveSheet.Paste   
                    End If
                End If
                'Close file
                wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I got to add that since I don't have a lot of knowledge in the VBA I use the built in macro recorder and than adapt it. I know this is not the best approach to programming in general but I don't have much time to learn a whole new programming language.

**Explanation of each file**

- **[Seller_Number]-[Seller_Name].xlsx:-** This file doesn't have a fixed number of rows and it always comes first on my Sheet 1, in my case it starts at Cell A25, and I don't want to copy the headers on this files
- **[Seller_Number]-[Seller_Name]-Debit.xlsx:-** This file also doesn't have a fixed number of rows and it can start anywhere in sheet 2, preferably after Range A4, I don't want to copy the headers on this files
- **[Seller_Number]-[Seller_Name]-Resume.xlsx:-** This file always has 2 rows (header and content), so I don't mind it being copied to range A1 on Sheet 2

Comment: Look at opening into `workbook` object and then `run` the macro in each.

Comment: Can you share the code you got so far? I mean the code for one set. My idea is to rewrite your procedure to contain the argument `[Seller_Number]-[Seller_Name]`. Then write another procedure which will write all the `[Seller_Number]-[Seller_Name]`s to a data structure (collection, dictionary, array list) and then loop through the data structure each time calling your now 'argumented' procedure.

Comment: @VBasic2008 just added the code that I've got.

Comment: If you don't mind posting the complete code from `Sub` to `End Sub` and any accompanying procedures (functions). Just change the sensitive information, e.g. for a folder "C:\Test"... If I write a code, your code would always overwrite the previous data which would make no sense, so there has to be other relevant code.

Comment: @VBasic2008 added code from `Sub` to `Endsub` I don't have any procedures.

Comment: I've looked at the code. The problem is if you would do this for all files, you would get the results of only the last data set (the data would be overwritten). Did you have in mind to write to different worksheets or each result below the other? Sheets(1) and Sheets(2) is not a good idea. You should rather use their names (in the tab) e.g. "Sheet1", "Sheet2". The worksheet in the source files should also be defined because they are probably the same in all workbooks. You are using A1 and A5 in the same worksheet which would mean that the RESUME workbook contains max 4 rows. Please do clarify.

Comment: RESUME workbook always has one row and both the DEBIT and the other workbook don't have max row, it will depend on the performance of the seller each month. I'd like it to open every workbook, copy to the specific ranges and then save it to some folder "C:\Test" with the name on cell `A2` for example, and repeat until there's no more files no the selected folder.

Comment: The order in which they should appear is RESUME on sheet two, normal workbook in range `A25`, and DEBIT right after, but without the first row as it is the header.

Answer (score 1):

### A Bunch of Excel Files

- This may not do what you expected, but could put you on the right path.
- After picking the desired folder, this solution will open each file (workbook) in it and copy the used ranges of their active worksheets to specific worksheets (depending on strings contained in the workbook name) of an already open workbook, one below the other.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub updateMasterWorkbook()

    Dim FolderPath As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = False Then Exit Sub
        FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    If FolderPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim FileName As String: FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "\*.xls*")
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks("Comission_TEMPLATE.xlsm")
    Dim rg1 As Range: Set rg1 = dwb.Worksheets(1).Range("A25")
    Dim rg2 As Range: Set rg2 = dwb.Worksheets(2).Range("A1")
    
    Dim swb As Workbook
    Dim n As Long
    
    Do Until Len(FileName) = 0
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "\" & FileName)
        If InStr(wb.Name, "-RESUME") Then
            With swb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
                .Copy rg2
                Set rg2 = rg2.Offset(.Rows.Count)
            End With
        ElseIf InStr(wb.Name, "-DEBIT") Then
            With swb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
                .Copy rg2
                Set rg2 = rg2.Offset(.Rows.Count)
            End With
        Else
            With swb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
                .Copy rg1
                Set rg1 = rg1.Offset(.Rows.Count)
            End With
        End If
        swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Debug.Print FileName, FolderPath
        FileName = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I added to my original question an explanation of each file and its contents. Thanks in advance, I tried this code and it worked, just not the way I intended to, but I understand that my lack of information made it harder. I will tinker with your code to see if I can come up with an answer to my problem